# Why we need abstract decorator class in Decorator Pattern?

Tags: java, scala, design-patterns, decorator

In `Decorator Pattern`,  if I

1. remove the *abstract decorator class* which decorators was inherit and
2. has *decorators* directly *inherit* the interface of *decoratee*.

The output is the same.

My question is why bother adding additional `abstractor class` to make a decorator ?

---

For example:

The `Scala` source code of standard `decorator pattern` is here: https://gist.github.com/kencoba/1875983

While my version that follow the above steps is as following:
(by removing the abstract decorator class (`CoffeeDecorator` here) and has decorators directly inherit the decoratee (`Coffee` here) )

```
trait Coffee {
  def cost: Double
  def ingredients: String
}

//abstract class CoffeeDecorator(decoratedCoffee: Coffee) extends Coffee {
//  val sep = ", "
//
//  override def cost = decoratedCoffee.cost
//  override def ingredients = decoratedCoffee.ingredients
//}

class Milk(decoratedCoffee: Coffee) extends Coffee {
  override def cost = decoratedCoffee.cost + 0.5
  override def ingredients = decoratedCoffee.ingredients + "," + "Milk"
}

class Whip(decoratedCoffee: Coffee) extends Coffee {
  override def cost = decoratedCoffee.cost + 0.7
  override def ingredients = decoratedCoffee.ingredients + "," + "Whip"
}


object DecoratorSample {... // same as the comparing source code.
```

Answer (score 1):

After fiddling around , I find the difference.
That abstract decorator provides the default overridings, so in some cases that gives decorator implementations less typings since we don't always decorates all methods and give common helpers.

```
trait Coffee {
  def cost: Double
  def ingredients: String
}

class FreeMilk(decoratedCoffee: Coffee) extends Coffee {
  // this is a waste of line
  override def cost = decoratedCoffee.cost 
  override def ingredients = decoratedCoffee.ingredients + "," + "Milk"
}

abstract class CoffeeDecorator(decoratedCoffee: Coffee) extends Coffee {
  val sep = ", "
  override def cost = decoratedCoffee.cost
  override def ingredients = decoratedCoffee.ingredients
}
class FreeMilk2(decoratedCoffee: Coffee) extends CoffeeDecorator(decoratedCoffee) {
  // less typings and give you some base helpers
  override def ingredients = super.ingredients + sep + "Milk"
}
```